# No consigo sumar una lista de MySQL con php

Tags: php, mysql

Igual parece una tontería pero llevo unos días intentando sumar una lista de una tabla `MySQL` con `php`. Pongo el código que tengo y lo que me sale.

```
    
<?php
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM PRUEBA ";                
$resultados=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)){

echo $mostrar['NOMBRE'];
echo "<br>";

}
$consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM PRUEBA ";                
$resultados2=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2);
while($mostrar2=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados2)){

echo $mostrar2['EDAD'];
echo "<br>";
}
$consulta3 = "SELECT SUM(EDAD) AS suma FROM PRUEBA ";                
$resultados3=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta3);

echo "$resultados3[suma]";
echo "<br>";

echo "Cerrando BBDD";    
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Me sale lo siguiente:

> Conectado con BBDD
>
> RAUL
>
> PACO
>
> MIGUEL
>
> 37
>
> 23
>
> 43
>
> Cerrando BBDD

Debería salir debajo de **43** la suma de las 3 edades (**103**)

El valor **EDAD** en la tabla es tipo **INT**

Que puedo hacer?

Gracias

Comment: Al menos yo no entiendo tu duda amigo, por favor considera explicarla mejor

Comment: No estás ejecutando `$consulta3`, por eso no obtienes sus resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que te has olvidado `mysqli_query()`

```
$consulta3 = "SELECT SUM(EDAD) AS suma FROM PRUEBA ";
$resultados3 = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta3);
$mostrar3 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados3);
echo "$mostrar3[suma]";
```

Comment: Gracias Dani, le habia dado tantas vueltas al tema que se me habia pasado la linea del query